# ASP.NET TargetSchema user control directive

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have several user controls that look like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" 
    Inherits="classname"
    TargetSchema="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5"
    Codebehind="classname.ascx.vb" 
 %>
```

I know that TargetSchema was supposed to give Visual Studio help with Intellisense when working with asp/html pages.  Does it still do anything or is it just ignored?  I don't see any obvious difference, and of course the version number is way out of date, but if it's still doing something useful, I wouldn't want to just delete it willy-nilly.

Comment: I think that was from VS 2003. Later versions, even since VS 2005 I think, they don't include it when creating new controls.

Comment: @TasosK.: that is a good point, I could just create a new control and see what it does...doesn't prove that it's not doing anything useful, but it would be a good indication that removing it wouldn't break much.